# Struggling with turn based game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, game-development

I am building a turn-based battle sequence in JavaScript that runs in the console of a browser.

I set my for-loop to keep going until the boss health is no longer greater than 0, then try to build if statements within the code for each turn. The problem is the for loop will continue running or when I reassign the player health inside an if statement, the scope is too far in and I can't return it.

One thing I've tried is a for loop where the assigned `int` would designate an event, but with `if` statements it skips numbers and does not pause. I need it to pause.

Here's the code:

```
for(let attackTurn = 0; bossHealth > 0; attackTurn++) {

    
    if (attackTurn%2 ==1) {
            attackChoice = prompt("1 or 2?");

            if(attackChoice == 1) {
                bossHealth = bossHealth - 30;
                console.log(bossHealth);
            } else if (attackChoice == 2) {
                bossHealth = bossHealth - 30;
                console.log(bossHealth);
        
            }
    }
}
```

I think the for loop idea is right but I just need to know how to implement it properly.

Comment: You mention that reassigning the player's health causes this for loop to continue iterating, but I can't see anything related to the player's health in your question. I tried your code as it is and the loop does actually end when boss' health gets <= 0. Can you post all the relevant code, please?

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding.

How do I post the full code? In a new post or do I message you?

Comment: @JosephLalo click "Edit"

Comment: @JosephLalo I posted an answer addressing your question.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much. This was really confusing since I'm new to even asking people for help. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code in order to include assignation of the player's health as well. I also added the ability for the boss to attack the player, with always the same attack that causes 10hp of damage. With this version, the game will come to and end and the iterations will end whenever the Boss or the Player run out of health.

Some remarks:

I) Since the game is turn-based, each iteration of the loop (each attackTurn) toggles between the Boss' attack and the Player's attack. You can group what happens in each turn by using an if-else:

```
 if (attackTurn%2 ==1) {
     // everything that happens during the Boss' turn.
 }
 else
 {
     // everything that happens during the Player's turn.
 }
```

II) The game must continue as long as both the Boss and the Player have some health points. For this reason, I updated the `for` condition to:

```
for(let attackTurn = 0; bossHealth > 0 && playerHealth > 0; attackTurn++)
```

III) Finally, note that you can log both characters health's at the end of the loop, you don't need to do it inside the `if` blocks:

Updated code:

```
let bossHealth = 100;
let playerHealth = 100;

for(let attackTurn = 0; bossHealth > 0 && playerHealth > 0; attackTurn++) {

    if (attackTurn%2 ==1) {
        attackChoice = prompt("It's the players turn. Choose an attack 1 or 2?");

        if(attackChoice == 1) {
            bossHealth = bossHealth - 10;

        } else if (attackChoice == 2) {
            bossHealth = bossHealth - 30;  
        }
    }

    else
    {
        alert("It's the Boss' turn. Boss uses 'Tackle'");
        playerHealth = playerHealth - 20;
    }

    console.log("Boss health:" + bossHealth);
    console.log("Player's health:" + playerHealth);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot. It got frustrating but you really made it easier to understand. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! let me know if you need more help.